# Как обрабатывать отрицательные параметры даты для LocalDateTime в JAVA?

Tags: java, datetime, localdate

В JS при создании даты из получаемых извне чисел, при передаче отрицательных значений:

```
new Date(1990, -2, -5);
```

получим корректную дату 26.10.1989

В JAVA есть аналогичный метод **Date**, который также формирует корректную дату при получении отрицательных параметров. Но беда в том, что он depricated. А также устарел и метод, который по документации его заменил (calendar который).
**LocalDateTime**, получая отрицательные значения, возвращает ошибку. Я понимаю, что ввод слегка "странный", но очень уж удобен, когда ты пытаешься косплеить Эксель, который не ругается на отрицательные значения, а автоматом вычитает дни/месяцы.
Собственно есть ли метод обрабатывающий красиво такую ситуацию? Или в ручную обрабатывать отрицательные значения и вешать математику?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LocalDateTime.MIN.withYear(1990).plusMonths(-2).plusDays(-5)
```

Правда получим 1989-10-27T00:00.

Comment: Да дошёл тоже до этой мысли, но гораздо более громоздким кодом. Спасибо ;)